# Install Chrome OS on a Bare Metal Atom box without virtualization

Tags: operating-systems, google-chrome-os

Is there any way to install ChromeOS on a small atom box without the use of Virtualization?

I've searched around and I can't seem to find any information other than XenClient installs and other virtualization solutions.

I'm looking to create browser terminals in our facility and I simply want to boot directly to a specific web page. What is the best way to do this? I'm hoping to boot extremely quickly, and that's why I've selected ChromeOS, however I am open to other operating systems (DLS, Ubuntu, etc) if they can boot quickly.

Answer (score 0):

I'd probably look at [hexxeh's builds](http://chromeos.hexxeh.net/) - they are slightly modified chromeos builds, i believe with extra drivers. They run off a USB key, but otherwise should fit what you want perfectly

Answer (score 0):

First download one of the builds and put it on your USB.
Then:

1. Boot up your USB stick and login
2. Press Control+Alt+T
3. Type the following without quotes “install /dev/sdX” where X is the number of the HDD you want to install to, usually 1 in most laptops/netbooks, eg “install /dev/sda”.
   Once the above command has finished running, you can reboot and remove the USB stick, and if all went well, you'll be booted from your HDD installation and ready for updates. -

(!) To find out your disk name / number type - “shell”, then “sudo fdisk -l” this will list your partitions, to exit the shell type “exit”

You might want to check this: https://web.archive.org/web/20110814065751/http://chromeos.hexxeh.net/wiki/doku.php?id=multiboot 
go to #3

Good luck.